# Full outer join of two dataframes

Tags: pandas, join, merge, outer-join

**Full outer join with keeping the joining key in all columns**

I have three dataframes with dimension m x 1, each dataframe with different m:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y':['A1', 'A3', 'A5', 'A4']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'z':['A1','A2', 'A5', 'A6']})
```

I one want a dataframe `df_merged` like this:

```
     x    y    z
0   A1   A1   A1
1   A2  nan   A2
2   A3   A3  nan
3   A4   A4  nan
4  nan   A5   A5
5  nan  nan   A6
```

Tried for hours to solve this using `pd.merge` and `pd.concat` and `pd.join`

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in list comprehension with create index by first column by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df = pd.concat([x.set_index(x.iloc[:, 0], drop=False) 
                for x in dfs], axis=1, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     x    y    z
0   A1   A1   A1
1   A2  NaN   A2
2   A3   A3  NaN
3   A4   A4  NaN
4  NaN   A5   A5
5  NaN  NaN   A6
```